# Kronecker tensor product in javascript

Tags: javascript, matlab

I need to calculate the Kronecker product of two matrices (like the kron() function in MatLab). I can't seem to find any code on it already, maybe someone has one lying on their computer tha is ready to use? I've already searched GitHub, and none of them seem to be working properly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

So for example:
`A = [1, 2];
B = [3, 4];
C =kroneckerProduct(A,B)`

C will then give [3, 4, 6, 8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the topic, I had to read it up. So I'm not entirely sure the code is works right *(for every input)*, though I checked it for some examples I found on the net.

```
function mapAB(a,b,fn){
    var k=0, out = Array(a.length*b.length);
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i)
        for(var j=0; j<b.length; ++j)
            out[k++] = fn(a[i], b[j]);
    return out;
}

function kroneckerProduct(a,b){
    return Array.isArray(a)?
        Array.isArray(b)? 
            mapAB(a,b, kroneckerProduct):
            a.map(v => kroneckerProduct(v, b)):
        Array.isArray(b)? 
            b.map(v => kroneckerProduct(a, v)):
            a*b;
}
```

```js
function mapAB(a, b, fn) {
  var k = 0,
    out = Array(a.length * b.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; ++j)
      out[k++] = fn(a[i], b[j]);
  return out;
}

function kroneckerProduct(a, b) {
  return Array.isArray(a) ?
    Array.isArray(b) ?
    mapAB(a, b, kroneckerProduct) :
    a.map(v => kroneckerProduct(v, b)) :
    Array.isArray(b) ?
    b.map(v => kroneckerProduct(a, v)) :
    a * b;
}

function compute() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var text;
  try {
    text = JSON.stringify(kroneckerProduct(
      JSON.parse(a.trim()),
      JSON.parse(b.trim())
    ), null, 2);
  } catch (err) {
    text = err;
  }

  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = text;

}
```

```html
<input id=a value=[1,2]><br>
<input id=b value=[3,4]><br>
<input type=button value=compute onclick=compute()>
<div id=out></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!